# Keep being prompted to enter passphrase for .ssh/id_rsa

Tags: git, bash, ssh, cygwin

I followed the tutorial [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) to set up ssh for github in cygwin on Window 7. However, every time I do `git push origin master`, I keep being prompted the following:

`Enter passphrase for /cygdrive/c/Users/mynameis/.ssh/id_rsa:`

This is so annoying because it beats the purpose of setting up ssh in the first place. I don't understand why it keeps prompting me for a password because when I did the same thing with my Mac and everything just worked fine and smooth.

I tried other solutions like: adding `eval ssh-agent -s`into my `.bashrc` . But the problem still remains. **I suspect the problem has to do with `ssh-agent` or `ssh-add` in cygwin on Window 7.** How can I get around this problem ?

Comment: Yes and Yes. But it asked me every time and I open a new cygwin window and every time i do git push

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add the following to your `~/.bash_profile`. When bash starts, this does two things: 1. starts the ssh-agent (otherwise it might spawn and die for each push/pull) and 2. tells the agent to remember your passphrase. In some Linux distributions, this happens automatically, unfortunately that isn't the case with Cygwin.

```
## only ask for my SSH key passphrase once!
#use existing ssh-agent if possible
if [ -f ${HOME}/.ssh-agent ]; then
   . ${HOME}/.ssh-agent > /dev/null
fi
if [ -z "$SSH_AGENT_PID" -o -z "`/usr/bin/ps -a|/usr/bin/egrep \"^[ ]+$SSH_AGENT_PID\"`" ]; then
   /usr/bin/ssh-agent > ${HOME}/.ssh-agent
   . ${HOME}/.ssh-agent > /dev/null
fi
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

See also:

- [Using passwordless login on PuTTY and Cygwin using Keys over SSH and SCP](http://www.edwardawebb.com/web-development/keys-putty-cygwin-passwordless-login-ssh-scp#repetitiveentryavoidanceakaenterthepassphraseonceandonlyonce)
- Or if you're using PoshGit... [Configure Git in PowerShell So You Don’t Have to Enter Your Password All the Damn Time](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/12/19/get-git-for-windows.aspx/)